# update 2 column using result from another select in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

[image]

I need to select distinct "col1" in table 1 and update "col1" and its class "col1Class" in table2

this is the code i wrote but its not working:

```
UPDATE testing 
SET col1 = a.col , Class = a.Class
from testing inner join 
( select distinct col1 , col1Class As col,class
from TestAll 
)a
```

Comment: How are rows in one table related to rows in the other table?  Your query is misformed because you have no `on` clause, so that would be one error in the code.

Comment: no im geting error :Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near 'a'.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff every column in table1 "col1,col2,..." have a class column in table 2 "col1" is the distinct of col1 in table 1 and it class value for every value

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes exactly its missing the on clause but i dont know how should i write it! :(

Comment: If you don't know how the tables related to each other, it is highly unlikely that you'll find a stranger on Stack Overflow who does.  This is your data, so you should understand what you want to do.  You can start by posting desired results based on the data you have in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
 UPDATE B 
 SET B.CLASS=A.CLASS
 FROM TESTING B
 JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT COL1 AS COL,COL1CLASS AS CLASS FROM TESTALL)A
 ON B.COL1=A.COL
```

Comment: what's the significance of selecting col1class from TestALL?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE testing 
SET col1 = A.col , Class = A.Class
FROM testing INNER JOIN 
(SELECT DISTINCT col1 , col1Class As col,class
from TestAll) 
as A 
ON testing.col1 = A.col AND testing.col1class = A.class
```

Comment: . . Look at the `on` condition.  Look at the `set` conditions (which should really be `col1class = A.class`).  Then ask yourself if this particular `update` is necessary.

Comment: @GordonLinoff o0ops i made a terrible mistake! i dont need to update my table i simply can use insert to! it was a bad mistake thanks you but now i'm using this but nothing inserted to my table2! `insert into testing (col2 , class2)
 select distinct col2 , col2Class 
from TestAll ` there is no error

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte(col1, colclass)
as
(
    select col1, colclass
    from table1
    group by col1,colclass
)

update t2
set col1 = c.col1, class = c.colClass
from table2 t2
inner join cte c on t2.col1 = c.col1
```

try this.